# Can a C# class-library read the web.config of a asp-classic web site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, class-library

I have a website which is build in Classic ASP. This website has a web.config file. I never created it, and never knew Classic ASP sites could have a web.config file, but this might be from IIS7 to store settings there.

This website uses a C# class library (DLL) to do some stuff. But here comes the tricky part. Should the DLL be able to read the web.config of this website?

I've copied the configSections from my app.config (from within the solution) to the web.config from the site. And also copied some settings (connectionstrings and applicationsettings). But when I changed the connectionstring to a faulty one, it would just keep running without a problem.

When I placed the configsections on the bottom of my web.config, the website wouldn't load because of a faulty web.config, so I the webserver is doing something with it. But can a C# DLL read this file also eventhough it's not a  .NET website?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C# can read any file.. not only config files.. It got System.IO :)

Comment: Yes, a C# Class Library can read the web.config file assuming you've imported the proper namespaces.

However, I'm not sure about Classic ASP. I didn't even think a Classic ASP program could use a .NET Class Library.

Comment: `web.config` was never used in Classic ASP.

Comment: web.config can be used for IIS settings, not just ASP.NET settings. For example, I use web.config on a Classic ASP website to set custom error pages (which are Classic ASP). Another example is that you can also enable/disable anonymous authentication on folders using web.config, even if it is just a static HTML website.

Comment: I would guess that the DLL would not be able to access the website's web.config automatically using System.Configuration and I'm not sure you can specify a path to the file. You would probably have to access it using System.IO and/or XML instead and would need appropriate file permissions.

Comment: @Murali, It was created before I started at this company. They had an Classic ASP website. And some functionality they created within a C# DLL (to keep the sourcecode for themselves, or maybe they had some functionality from other (C# projects the would use)). My biggest question was, why was the website not written in C# ;)

And yes, I could use System.IO to access the file, but it would have been so mutch easier if I could use System.Configuration :)

Answer (score 1):

As Chris said, asp classic does not use it, so it must have been created by IIS7 (or someone putting it there as a joke). That its not used if confirmed by your changing settings having no effect.

When you copied sections, the file becomes an invalid config; it's probably that which is causing it not to run, though what's checking it I don't know.

Another possibility is that the ASP website is using a C# library via COM Interop, and the run-time is checking its validity when it starts.

Comment: Since IIS7, web.config is often automatically added when certain IIS settings (or settings from some hosting control panels) are changed. There are many useful settings in web.config that can apply to Classic ASP, eg. custom error pages, URL rewriting, folder authentication.

Comment: I think the web.config is indeed created by IIS7. But still no-one can confirm it would or would not work to read this from a DLL called from a .asp file. I'll have to create a test-project to try it when I find the time I guess :)